# Using Oracle CLOB value inside MERGE

Tags: oracle, clob, sql-merge

I tried to copy values between tables with this query:

```
MERGE INTO workflow W
   USING ( 
       SELECT distinct pr.workflow_id, pr.name, pr.description FROM workflow_revision pr, workflow pw WHERE pw.id = pr.workflow_id 
   )WR
   ON ( W.id = WR.workflow_id )
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET W.name = WR.name, W.description = WR.description
```

But it gives, the following error: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`

When remove that **description** column from the query then it works fine. It's a **longtext**.

I just don't know how to fix this. Can you help me?

---

As @eaolson requested the layout of the tables, I give the original screenshot:
[image]

---

After @Lukasz Szozda 's commit I took this as answer:

```
MERGE INTO workflow W
USING (
   SELECT workflow_id, name, (CAST (description AS VARCHAR2(4000))) AS description FROM workflow_revision
)WR
ON (W.id = WR.workflow_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET W.name = WR.name, W.description = WR.description;
```

But as he also warned; this is a accaptable answer as long as the description column length max 4000(or the value you give in there) is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `JOIN`:

```
MERGE INTO workflow W
USING (SELECT workflow_id, name, description FROM workflow_revision)WR
   ON (W.id = WR.workflow_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET W.name = WR.name, W.description = TO_LOB(WR.description);
```

Comment: it still gives the error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`

Comment: @KorkiKorkig Please try: `W.description = TO_LOB(WR.description)`

Comment: unfortunately got the same error. Also tried to `TO_LOB(description) AS description` above

Comment: This works for me, can you show your table definitions?

Comment: @eaolson I've added a original screenshot of the tables. By the way, it seems that in `SELECT` of `USING`, changing into `(CAST (description AS VARCHAR2(4000))) AS description` solves the issue, but I'm not quit sure if this is a acceptable fix?

Comment: @KorkiKorkig As long as your description has max 4000 characters then yes, it is acceptable.